# Using Multiple ActionListeners in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

My problem is that at the moment I am making a GUI for a game and this GUI has many buttons. I had a problem earlier in my code where the `actionListener` I was using was looking for events in two buttons in rapid succession, not giving enough time for the second button to perform and action and rendering it useless. I thought I overcame that by making the second button a different `actionListener` in an inner class

```
button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

and now I'm trying to do the same for a third (and eventually fourth and fifth button

```
P1Roll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
```

but it is throwing me all kinds of errors. As I am very new to swing, I am unsure how to proceed. Any tips on this, or anything in my code at all would be very much appreciated.   :)

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class GUI_Windows extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GUI_Windows();

        Random rand1, rand2, rand3, rand4;
        int dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4;
        int numTurns = Turns.getValue();

        rand1 = new Random();
        rand2 = new Random();
        rand3 = new Random();
        rand4 = new Random();

        dice1 = rand1.nextInt(6 - 1 + 1) + 1;
        dice2 = rand2.nextInt(6 - 1 + 1) + 1;
        dice3 = rand3.nextInt(6 - 1 + 1) + 1;
        dice4 = rand4.nextInt(6 - 1 + 1) + 1;

    }

    Box MegaBox, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6, box7, box8, box9, box10,
            box11;

    Box Minibox1, Minibox2, Minibox3, Minibox4, Minibox5, MiniMegaBox;

    Box MegaBox2, box12, box13, box14, box15, box16, box17, box18, box19,
            box20, box21, box22, box23;

    JLabel TitleLabel, InstructionLabel, Instructions, SelectMode, LoG;

    Border spacer1 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 50, 5);
    Border spacer2 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 60, 5, 0);
    Border spacer3 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 5, 60);
    Border spacer4 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 5, 45);
    Border spacer5 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 6, 0);
    Border spacer6 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 10, 0, 70);
    Border spacer7 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 35);

    JRadioButton button1, button2;

    JButton button3, button4;

    JButton button5, button6;

    static JSlider Turns;

    public GUI_Windows() {

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                button3.doClick();
            }
        });

        this.setTitle("Bottom Out!");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocation(500, 125);
        this.setSize(350, 421);

        MegaBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

        box1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box1.setBorder(spacer1);
        box2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box2.setBorder(spacer2);

        box3 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box4 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box4.setBorder(spacer3);

        box5 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box5.setBorder(spacer5);

        box6 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box7 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box8 = Box.createHorizontalBox();

        box9 = Box.createHorizontalBox();

        box10 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box10.setBorder(spacer7);

        box11 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box11.setBorder(spacer6);

        button1 = new JRadioButton();
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2 = new JRadioButton();
        button2.addActionListener(this);

        TitleLabel = new JLabel("BOTTOM OUT");
        TitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        TitleLabel.setAlignmentY(1);

        InstructionLabel = new JLabel("Instructions:");
        InstructionLabel.setAlignmentY(0);
        InstructionLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));

        Instructions = new JLabel();
        Instructions.setAlignmentY(0);
        Instructions
                .setText("<HTML>Each game will be 3 - 20 turns, with either One Player versus the Computer, or Two Players "
                        + "versus each other. Each turn, you will roll two die, and then the two die are totaled up, and "
                        + "multiplied by the number of the roll it is for that turn. If this total is equal to, or higher than the "
                        + "total of your last scores in that turn, than you add those points to your score for that turn. Then you "
                        + "may choose to roll again, or end your turn to lock in your points for that turn.</HTML>");

        SelectMode = new JLabel("Select Mode:");
        SelectMode.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));

        LoG = new JLabel("Select number of Turns:");

        Turns = new JSlider(2, 20, 2);
        Turns.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
        Turns.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        Turns.setPaintTicks(true);
        Turns.setPaintLabels(true);
        Turns.setSnapToTicks(true);

        button3 = new JButton("Quit");
        button3.setVisible(true);
        button3.addActionListener(this);

        button4 = new JButton("Next");
        button4.setVisible(true);
        button4.addActionListener(this);

        button5 = new JButton("Done");
        button5.setVisible(true);
        // button5.addActionListener(this);

        button6 = new JButton("Done");
        button6.setVisible(true);
        button6.addActionListener(this);

        ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
        group1.add(button1);
        group1.add(button2);

        ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
        group2.add(button3);
        group2.add(button4);

        box6.add(TitleLabel);
        box7.add(InstructionLabel);
        box7.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box7.add(new JLabel(" "));
        box8.add(Instructions);

        box3.add(SelectMode);
        box3.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box3.add(new JLabel(" "));

        box4.add(button1);
        box4.add(new JLabel(" One Player"));
        box4.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box4.add(button2);
        box4.add(new JLabel(" Two Players"));

        box9.add(LoG);
        box9.setBorder(spacer4);

        box10.add(Turns);
        box10.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box10.add(new JLabel(" "));

        box11.add(button3);
        box11.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box11.add(button4);

        box1.add(box6);
        box1.add(box7);
        box1.add(box8);

        box5.add(box3);
        box5.add(box4);

        box2.add(box5);
        box2.add(box9);
        box2.add(box10);
        box2.add(box11);

        MegaBox.add(box1);
        MegaBox.add(box2);

        this.add(MegaBox);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    int onePlayer = 0;
    int isDone = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == button3) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (button1.isSelected()) {
            onePlayer = 1;
        } else if (button2.isSelected()) {
            onePlayer = 2;
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button4 && onePlayer == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button1,
                    "You must select the number of players!", "Try again!",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } else if (e.getSource() == button4 && onePlayer != 0) {

            final JFrame pFrame = new JFrame();

            pFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pFrame.setTitle("Bottom Out!");
            pFrame.setResizable(false);
            pFrame.setLocation(500, 125);
            pFrame.setSize(250, 200);

            JLabel EnterName1, EnterName2;

            final JTextField NameBox1;
            final JTextField NameBox2;

            Border border1 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 25, 15, 25);
            Border border2 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 25, 5, 25);
            Border border3 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 5, 0);

            EnterName1 = new JLabel("Player 1, please enter your name:");
            EnterName2 = new JLabel("Player 2, please enter your name:");

            NameBox1 = new JTextField("Miller");
            NameBox2 = new JTextField("Julian");

            if (onePlayer == 1) {
                NameBox2.setEditable(false);
                NameBox2.setText("Watson");
            }

            Minibox1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
            Minibox2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
            Minibox3 = Box.createVerticalBox();
            Minibox4 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            MiniMegaBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

            Minibox1.add(EnterName1);
            Minibox1.add(NameBox1);
            Minibox1.setBorder(border1);

            Minibox2.add(EnterName2);
            Minibox2.add(NameBox2);
            Minibox2.setBorder(border2);

            Minibox3.add(Minibox1);
            Minibox3.add(Minibox2);

            Minibox4.add(new JLabel(" "));
            Minibox4.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
            Minibox4.add(button5);
            Minibox4.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
            Minibox4.add(new JLabel(" "));
            Minibox4.setBorder(border3);

            MiniMegaBox.add(Minibox3);
            MiniMegaBox.add(Minibox4);

            pFrame.add(MiniMegaBox);

            pFrame.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);

            button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if (e.getSource() == button5) {

                        Border spaceBorder1 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                45, 45, 15, 45);
                        Border spaceBorder2 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                15, 45, 30, 45);
                        Border spaceBorder3 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                5, 15, 5, 0);
                        Border spaceBorder4 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                5, 0, 10, 10);
                        Border spaceborder5 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                0, 0, 15, 0);
                        Border spaceborder6 = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                                15, 0, 0, 0);

                        JFrame gFrame = new JFrame();
                        gFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        gFrame.setTitle("Bottom Out!");
                        gFrame.setResizable(false);
                        gFrame.setLocation(500, 125);
                        gFrame.setSize(350, 421);

                        TitleLabel = new JLabel("BOTTOM OUT");
                        TitleLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",
                                Font.BOLD, 20));
                        TitleLabel.setAlignmentY(1);
                        box23 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box23.add(TitleLabel);
                        box23.setBorder(spaceborder6);

                        box12 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box12.setBorder(spaceBorder1);
                        box13 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box13.setBorder(spaceBorder2);
                        box14 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box14.setBorder(spaceborder5);

                        box15 = Box.createVerticalBox();

                        box16 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box16.setBorder(spaceBorder3);
                        box17 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box17.setBorder(spaceBorder3);
                        box18 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box18.setBorder(spaceBorder3);
                        box19 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box19.setBorder(spaceBorder3);
                        box20 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box20.setBorder(spaceBorder3);
                        box21 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                        box21.setBorder(spaceBorder4);

                        box22 = Box.createVerticalBox();

                        MegaBox2 = Box.createVerticalBox();

                        JLabel Player1, Player2, P1Score, P2Score;

                        JButton P1Roll, P2Roll, EndTurn;

                        JLabel TurnNum, TurnMax, TurnsRem, P1TScore, P2TScore, Winner;

                        Player1 = new JLabel(NameBox1.getText() + ":");
                        P1Score = new JLabel("Score");
                        P1Roll = new JButton("Roll!");

                        Player2 = new JLabel(NameBox2.getText() + ":");
                        P2Score = new JLabel("Score");
                        P2Roll = new JButton("Roll!");

                        EndTurn = new JButton("End Turn");

                        TurnNum = new JLabel("Turn Number: ");
                        TurnMax = new JLabel("Turn max: ");
                        TurnsRem = new JLabel("Turns left: ");
                        P1TScore = new JLabel("Player 1 Score: ");
                        P2TScore = new JLabel("Player 2 Score: ");
                        Winner = new JLabel("Player is Winning");

                        box12.add(Player1);
                        box12.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box12.add(P1Score);
                        box12.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box12.add(P1Roll);

                        box13.add(Player2);
                        box13.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box13.add(P2Score);
                        box13.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box13.add(P2Roll);

                        box14.add(new JLabel(" "));
                        box14.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box14.add(EndTurn);
                        box14.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box14.add(new JLabel(" "));

                        box15.add(box23);
                        box15.add(box12);
                        box15.add(box13);
                        box15.add(box14);

                        box16.add(TurnNum);
                        box16.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box16.add(new JLabel(" "));
                        box17.add(TurnMax);
                        box17.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box17.add(new JLabel(" "));
                        box18.add(TurnsRem);
                        box18.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box18.add(new JLabel(" "));
                        box19.add(P1TScore);
                        box19.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box19.add(new JLabel(" "));
                        box20.add(P2TScore);
                        box20.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box20.add(new JLabel(" "));
                        box21.add(new JLabel(" "));
                        box21.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                        box21.add(Winner);

                        box22.add(box16);
                        box22.add(box17);
                        box22.add(box18);
                        box22.add(box19);
                        box22.add(box20);
                        box22.add(box21);

                        MegaBox2.add(box15);
                        MegaBox2.add(box22);

                        gFrame.add(MegaBox2);

                        gFrame.setVisible(true);
                        pFrame.setVisible(false);

P1Roll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    int turnNum;

    for(turnNum; numTurns > 0 ; numTurns -- ){

    }




}});

                    }
                }
            });
        }


}}
```

Comment: More details on exactly what errors you're getting would aid greatly in solving the problem.

Comment: welcome here :-) first strip your code down to the fewest number of LOC that's showing the problem (search for sscce or similar, Andrew Thompson explains it quite nicely) as rarely anybody is inclined to read tons of unrelated code. More often than not, you'll find the problem yourself in doing so :-)

Comment: thanks for the tip, its nice to see when people are welcoming and explain things for a newbie.   :P  I hope to see you around, and look forward to it

Comment: You wrote: "*I was using was looking for events in two buttons in rapid succession, not giving enough time for the second button to perform and action and rendering it useless.*" I am not sure what you meant by that. The handling of one action should not interfere with the handling of another. Think of a calculator. Button presses don't interfere with each other.  That said, you must code so that the action being perform don't interfere with the GUI. So, when you need to execute code that is process-intensive, make sure you do so in a daemon thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an initial reading of the code, it appears you're creating the anonymous ActionListener with incorrect syntax.

```
P1Roll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    int turnNum;

    for(turnNum; numTurns > 0 ; numTurns -- ){

    }




}});
```

Should be

```
P1Roll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    int turnNum;
    for(turnNum; numTurns > 0 ; numTurns -- )
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: in the first code snippet, the outer `actionPerformed` is correct since his class implements `ActionListener` also, the inner anonymous `ActionListener`  should override `actionPerformed`, not `ActionPerformed` since the latter doesn't exist.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the quick response! :)
Secondly, I have trider using this (the @override was a quickfix suggestion by eclipse) but it just gives me this error, which I couldnt find anywhere on google: Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete ForInit

Comment: @mre - Fixed, I had not looked that in his code, so I copied, pasted and edited. That one slipped through. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ok, well let me explain a little more about the errors I'm getting right around the last chunk of the code. When I try to create the anonymoud actionListener, I enter it all in correctly (braces, brackets and semicolons included) and it red underlines a bunch of the braces i already had for my other classes and such saying that I should delete them, or add some in in other places. I tried following this, but it keeps saying it no matter what I do, making me think that it's something to do with what I'm trying to add. I just can't figure it out since the syntax on that code specifically is rit

Comment: Thank you very much, as I think (so far) that the problem is solved. It seems as though it was just a simple syntax error, that thanks to you I have corrected!  :) Enjoy your rep!  :P